# Error running AppImage "fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted" on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, permissions, mount, fuse, appimage

I'm trying to run an AppImage executable file. However, I see the following error message when I run it:

```
$ jetbrains-toolbox 
fusermount: mount failed: Operation not permitted

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

I have `fuse` installed and it looks like it's configured properly but I still see the error. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Ubuntu 20.04, completely reinstalling `fuse` helps.

Either with:

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove fuse
sudo apt-get install fuse
```

or less intrusive

```
sudo apt --reinstall install fuse
```

Source information: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TBX-3544

Comment: what if doesn't help?